# И еще об ударениях, как правильно: "флюорогрАфия" или "флюорографИя"?

Tags: фонетика

-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для нормальных людей - флюроогр***а***фия. Но в профессиональной деятельности возможно смещения ударения на предпоследний слог: флюроограф***и***я.

По материалам [яндекс.словарей](http://slovari.yandex.ru/%D1%84%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/)